# Panel body is not resizing when table is big?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a panel and I am putting bootstrap table inside it, but table is not fitting under it, when it is big.

```js
var table = $("<table class='table'>");
table.append($("<thead><tr><th scope='col'>col1</th><th scope='col'>col2</th><th scope='col'>col3</th><th scope='col'>col4</th><th scope='col'>col5</th><th scope='col'>col6</th><th scope='col'>col7</th><th scope='col'>col8</th><th scope='col'>col9</th><th scope='col'>col10</th><th scope='col'>col11</th><th scope='col'>col12</th><th scope='col'>col13</th></tr><thead/>"));
for(var i=0; i<10 ; i++)
{
var row = $('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>' + "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "6" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "7" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "8" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "9" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "10" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "11" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "12" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "13" + '</td></tr><tbody/>');

table.append(row);

}


$("#table").html(table);
$("#table").show();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Title Here</div>
  <div id="tablePanelBody" class="panel-body">
    <table id="table">

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to create table dynamically and putting under panel body . I want to make body panel adjust according to table size and also to be able to scroll vertically

Comment: Use __table-responsive__ class of bootstrap to resize accordingly , just try it once.

Comment: and check this `"11" + '</td' + '<td>' + "12"` (the missing **>** on `td`)

Comment: I have answered below. Check it. [Table_responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59623259/11657467)

Answer (score 1):

As per bootstrap documentation `class="table-responsive"` is used for responsive table, And you can find responsive table inside `panel`

```js
var table = $("<table class='table'>");
table.append($("<thead><tr><th scope='col'>col1</th><th scope='col'>col2</th><th scope='col'>col3</th><th scope='col'>col4</th><th scope='col'>col5</th><th scope='col'>col6</th><th scope='col'>col7</th><th scope='col'>col8</th><th scope='col'>col9</th><th scope='col'>col10</th><th scope='col'>col11</th><th scope='col'>col12</th><th scope='col'>col13</th></tr><thead/>"));
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var row = $('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>' + "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "6" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "7" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "8" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "9" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "10" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "11" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "12" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "13" + '</td></tr><tbody/>');

  table.append(row);

}

$("#table").html(table);
$("#table").show();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Title Here</div>
  <div id="tablePanelBody" class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="table" style="max-height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As per request you need a vertical scroll bar this `css` `style="max-height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;"` will create vertical scroll if content is more that `300px` you can change it to your wish.
**FYI**
you can add above `css` to `panel` or can add it to `table` as per your wish.

Comment: I want to scroll table vertically also, how i can do that?

Comment: you didn't mention that on your question, and you need to add more row to create vertical scroll.

Comment: check now, could you help ? @sanoj

Comment: @Rahul FYI bootstrap has more advanced feature in `4.4` https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `<table>` directly into another `<table>` which is wrong coding standard. Add `<div class="table-responsive">` then append your table markup into it.

```js
var table = $("<table class='table'>");
table.append($("<thead><tr><th scope='col'>col1</th><th scope='col'>col2</th><th scope='col'>col3</th><th scope='col'>col4</th><th scope='col'>col5</th><th scope='col'>col6</th><th scope='col'>col7</th><th scope='col'>col8</th><th scope='col'>col9</th><th scope='col'>col10</th><th scope='col'>col11</th><th scope='col'>col12</th><th scope='col'>col13</th></tr><thead/>"));
var row = $('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>' + "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "6" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "7" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "8" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "9" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "10" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "11" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "12" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "13" + '</td></tr><tbody/>');

table.append(row);

$("#table").html(table);
$("#table").show();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Title Here</div>
  <div id="tablePanelBody" class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="table">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to scroll my table vertically, can you help? @Asfan

Comment: @Rahul When you resize your screen, vertical scroll bar will be automatically added.

Comment: @Rahul or you can give fixed width to table or each cell of table using CSS which size should be greater than it's table parent container width.

Comment: Vertically scroll is starting from body panel but not from table like horizontal scroll @Asfan link - https://jsfiddle.net/7kp83qy2/

Comment: @Rahul Do you need sticky header and vertical scroll of your table?